# Can we make dynamic document in firestore using angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I want doc("") containing dynamic ID to fetch the values of that dynamic document. If i have two documents under same collection named document1 and document2 then, how can i give the dynamic path having dynamic documentName to fetch the value of particular document which i want?

```
 this.items = db.collection("First").doc("dynamicId").collection("Second").valueChanges();
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use variables to make documents dynamic, as follows:

```
var collection = "First";
var document = "document1";
this.items = db.collection(collection).doc(document);
```